# MovableFloatingActionButton does not receive onTouch when over top of a AppBarLayout that contains CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I used some code I found here to add a MovableFloatingActionButton (this object extends the FloatingActionButton, just makes it movable) to my MainActivity.  The MovableFloatingActionButton moves around the screen just fine including the CollapsingToolbarLayout area but once I release my finger from the screen and then try to move the FloatingActionButton again, the AppBarLayout starts moving (in vertical direction) instead of the MovableFloatingActionButton in the vertical direction.  Is there not some flag in the AppBarLayout to tell it not to take over onTouch() commands from objects hovered over top of it?

I have used the AppBarLayout behavior.setDragCallback work around to make the AppBarLayout stop taking over the onTouch but is not optimal because this disables the ability for the AppBarLayout to be touched to scroll the entire View up and down.  Inside the "layout/content_main" is just a LinearLayout with a RecyclerView that shows a List below the CollapsingToolbarLayout area.   Inside the CollapsingToolbarLayout is a LinearLayout of 8 vertically stacked TextViews.

```
activity_main.xml
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        >
        <!--app:layout_behavior="com.ktoonsez.golfclubtracker.FixedAppBarLayoutBehavior"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"-->

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <!--<ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/background_sky"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="156dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                />-->

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.ktoonsez.golfclubtracker.MovableFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mylocation" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Example of what I used to override the vertical drag

```
        appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout);

        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
        params.setBehavior(new AppBarLayout.Behavior());
        //params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
        AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();
        behavior.setDragCallback(new AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback() {
            @Override
            public boolean canDrag(@NonNull AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
                return false; //Globals.AppBarLayoutCanDrag;
            }
        });
```

So in the end I just want to be able to move my MovableFloatingActionButton all around the entire screen (the RecyclerView area and the AppBarLayout area) and still be able to scroll from the AppBarLayout (the area is pretty large, about 1/3rd to 1/4th of the screen depending on the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I came up with to solve my problem:

Created a class that extends "AppBarLayout.Behavior" like so.  The key was to Override the onInterceptTouchEvent() function and return false.

```
public class AppBarLayoutBehavior extends AppBarLayout.Behavior {

    public AppBarLayoutBehavior() {
        super();
    }

    public AppBarLayoutBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout parent, AppBarLayout child, MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Then added the line below to the AppBarLayout in the activity_main.xml:

```
app:layout_behavior="com.codename.AppBarLayoutBehavior"
```

Just to recap, this allowed the AppBarLayout to be touched and allow itself and the rest of the screen to scroll and at the same time not take over the drag/touch functions of my overlaying MovableFloatingActionButton if that was the area of the AppBarLayout that was touched.